# Rearrange list into a dataframe and

Tags: r, list, dataframe

There is a list with different sublists of different length

```
l
[[1]] 3,4,5,7,8
[[2]] 4,5,7
[[3]] 3,9
[[4]] 6,7,8,10
```

How can I reorder the list to be a data frame in which the cols are the sublists 1 to 4? The rest should be filled up with NA. Can I then use melt on this data frame?

Answer (score 3):

With `stringi` package

```
library(stringi)
(Res <- stri_list2matrix(a))
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
# [1,] "3"  "4"  "3"  "6" 
# [2,] "4"  "5"  "9"  "7" 
# [3,] "5"  "7"  NA   "8" 
# [4,] "7"  NA   NA   "10"
# [5,] "8"  NA   NA   NA
```

If you want them to be numeric class, could add the following line

```
(Res <- matrix(as.numeric(Res), ncol = ncol(Res)))
# Res
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
# [1,]    3    4    3    6
# [2,]    4    5    9    7
# [3,]    5    7   NA    8
# [4,]    7   NA   NA   10
# [5,]    8   NA   NA   NA
```

Answer (score 2):

You could try something like this:

```
#create some dummy date
a<-list(c(3,4,5,7,8),c(4,5,7),c(3,9),c(6,7,8,10))

#get the longest vector
m<-max(sapply(a,length))

#fill in the sublists with NAs so that they all have the same length
as.data.frame(sapply(a,function(x){length(x)<-m;x}))


#  V1 V2 V3 V4
#1  3  4  3  6
#2  4  5  9  7
#3  5  7 NA  8
#4  7 NA NA 10
#5  8 NA NA NA
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do as follows: 
The following add zeros instead NA

```
a<-list(c(3,4,5,7,8),c(4,5,7),c(3,9),c(6,7,8,10))

n.col <- vapply(a, length, 1L)
mat <- matrix(0, nrow = length(a), ncol = max(n.col))
rand <- cbind(rep(seq_along(n.col), times = n.col), sequence(n.col))
M[rand] <- unlist(a, use.names = FALSE)
M2 <- t(M)
print(M2)

#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
#[1,]    3    4    3    6
#[2,]    4    5    9    7
#[3,]    5    7    0    8
#[4,]    7    0    0   10
#[5,]    8    0    0    0
```

if you want now to have NA instead zero , you can do as follows:

```
M2[M2 == 0] <- NA
print(M2)
#    [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
#[1,]    3    4    3    6
#[2,]    4    5    9    7
#[3,]    5    7   NA    8
#[4,]    7   NA   NA   10
#[5,]    8   NA   NA   NA
```